# How can i redirect my home page without loading the components first?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to redirect my beta app.
When I open the home page, it should be redirected to another page. I am using `window.location` on `app.component` but it's starting to load the components first and then redirecting so it looks kind of weird.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.location = String(window.location);
    console.log('this.location);

    if (this.location === 'http://localhost:4200/home') {
        window.location.replace('https://www.google.com/');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what [guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication) are used for.

Comment: Should it redirect to another page if user is not authenticated or in all condition it should redirect to another page?

Comment: I think that you're looking for loadChildren -so only load a minimum components- https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NavigationStart event of router and subscribe it in your constructor like below :

```
constructor(router:Router) {
   router.events.subscribe(event => {
     if(event instanceof NavigationStart) { //  import {  NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
         if (this.location === 'http://localhost:4200/home') {
            window.location.replace('https://www.google.com/');
         }
     }
```

}
});

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component( {
    selector: 'app-viewtables',
    templateUrl: './viewtables.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./viewtables.component.css']
} )
export class Home{
    constructor(private router: Router ) {
             this.router.navigate( ['/secondpage'] );
        }
    }
```